# Collection Reusable View not being displayed with custom Layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I've created at the beginning a UICollectionView With a CollectionReusableView and implemented the needed delegate methods :

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

By doing this, the collectionView Header was displayed correctly. But the problem was detected when I changed the CollectionViewLayout to a custom one (Not the Flow Layout), the Header View was not being displayed anymore.
When debugging, I saw that the delegate method viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind: atIndexPath:  was not being called.

Note That I am using the [RFQuiltLayout](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout) as the UICollectionView Layout.

Thanks in advance for your help